# Laravel Eloquent distinct timestamp's year

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

On some indexes I have selectboxes that filter results, 1 of them filters by year. But this selectbox only needs the years present in the related table. After doing some research on the net I came up with this:

```
public function getAvailableYears(string $column)
{
    $years = $this->model->selectRaw("substr({$column},1,4) as year")
                         ->distinct('year')
                         ->pluck('year', 'year')
                         ->toArray();

    return ['' => 'All'] + $years;
}
```

This perfectly produces an array ready to be inserted into Form::select()

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. It seems to work fine since the timestamps always start with the year, but I am not sure about performance or other issues I might encounter in the future. Any expert insight would be awesome.

Comment: Is `DATE_FORMAT(...)` not an option here for some reason? What's the datatype of `{$column}`? I feel like `substr` isn't the best approach for pulling a static `year` value from a column; open to unexpected data

Comment: $column is the targeted column, like `starts_at` in this case or `published_at` at another. I feel ya, codesmell. I was thinking maybe I don't need a shared function, since there is already a collection passed on to the index. Maybe I could handle every index individually and use this Collection

Comment: Well, the idea would work, since `starts_at` and `published_at` *should* be `datetime` or `timestamp` columns, so instead of using `substr`, use `DATE_FORMAT({$column}, "%Y")`; my comment was more relying on stripping a date out of a `VARCHAR` column, which shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: What about using YEAR function? `EXTRACT(year FROM creation_date)`

Comment: ended up using Tim Lewis' suggestion. Using the collection didn't seem like a good idea because of pagination. Also I removed the placeholder from the function to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 6):

I was also trying to create a dropdown of years for a report module and wanted to get the unique years from a DB table, particularly the 'created_at' field. Came up with this after a lot of trying and tinker-ing. Result's an array already, no need to convert it.

Try this:

```
$result = App\ModelName::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year'))->distinct()->get();
$years = $result->pluck('year');
```

Comment: The downside to using YEAR() is it's not compatible with SQLite, so if you're using it for tests your tests will fail.

Comment: If you're a programmer Sir, you need to learn to be dynamic. I posted an answer & also an idea. If you're using a different DB platform then adapt the code to your platform. I can't possibly cover all the existing platforms for everyone's convenience.

Comment: I’m very dynamic. I was just simply posting a downfall with your solution so that when someone’s reading through here they would understand why they should or shouldn’t use your solution. No need to get your panties in a wad.

Answer (score 1):

I used this method for distinct year from date column.

```
tableModel::whereNotNull('columnName')->distinct()->get([DB::raw('YEAR(columnName) as year')]);
```